# When using cordova to package apk files, why is this error

Tags: cordova, ionic3

When using cordova to package apk files

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBl2R.jpg)

why???

Comment: Its Better to Include the Error as a Part of Question.

Comment: Show us the whole output of the command, in your screen you just show the end of the output, which does not contain the cause of the error

Answer (score 0):

Just line suggested run with the `--verbose` option to get more information on the error. And your screenshot doesn't show the part of the actual error.